# Paste image from my clipboard below the last image

Tags: excel, vba

i need help in the creation of the macro. Ill try to explain the function i want it to have:

- With the screenshot already on my clipboard, I need all the different screenshot, that are going below the blue rectangle, to mantain the same width (30,4cm) and column (B:B) of this rectangle).
  Below I show an example of what I need. Therefore, every time I paste a new screenshot the macro should search the last image and put the new one beneath the last one.
- Also, it would be perfect if between each screenshot it would mantain a gap.

[image: For Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help get you started.  This macro/function will line up all images under that blue shape that starts in A1 in the order that they have been pasted into the worksheet.  A small gap will be between them and they will be resized to match the width of the header shape.

```
Sub LineUpAllShapes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape, shpHeader As Shape
    Dim colOtherShapes As New Collection
    Dim prvShape As Shape
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Column = 1 And shp.TopLeftCell.Row = 1 Then
            Set shpHeader = shp
        Else
            colOtherShapes.Add shp
        End If
    Next shp
    
    If Not shpHeader Is Nothing Then
        Set prvShape = shpHeader
        
        For Each shp In colOtherShapes
            shp.Width = prvShape.Width
            shp.Top = prvShape.Top + prvShape.Height + 5
            shp.Left = prvShape.Left
            
            'add border to image
            shp.DrawingObject.Border.LineStyle = 1
            shp.DrawingObject.Border.Color = vbBlack
            shp.DrawingObject.Border.Weight = 2
            
            Set prvShape = shp
        Next shp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Daniel, your macro works perfectly as I needed! However I need to make two questions;
# 1- I created an extra macro that calls your macro. Can we improve this; (https://postimg.cc/75GVtF8p)
# 2- I need to add a border around the image that are pasted in the sheet. Can you add the code to your macro? (https://postimg.cc/XpvxdZ2N)